# Cannot override System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol to Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol

Tags: web-services, reference, wse, soaphttpclientprotocol

My Website (3.5 version) has a web reference to an external web service created in App_WebReference folder. This folder does not have Reference.cs (.wsdl and .discomap only available) . I can find the proxy classes in the dll inside the ASP.NET temporary folder located at:
C:\Users\Amit\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Temporary ASP.NET Files\core_webservices\2e1ad39b_shadow\16784daa\249954494\30312779\App_WebReferences.c1uisrry.dll

Here is the class declaration:
**public class Service1 : SoapHttpClientProtocol**

I can not edit it as it's showing in the DLL.

I need to override the inheritance to as below so that I can create WSE 2.0 supported SOAP message:

**Public class Service1 : Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol**

Please help. Thank you!

I am using VS Studio 2010 + WSE 2.0

Comment: To fix this, I created a Class library and in that I added the web reference to external web services. I was able to get Reference.cs and then overridden the class as per need and then added the DLL reference into my Website's bin folder. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change in refernce file generated to below :

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
 to
Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol

You should be good to go.